# Layout Primera columna que colapse tres filas

Tags: android

estoy comenzando con android y me surge un tema. 
Tengo lo que se ve en la imagen 1, y quiero que la fecha se muestre a la izquierda ocupando las tes lineas de la derecha. como en la imagen 2.
Como puedo hacer?

[image: Imagen1]

[image: Imagen 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderDateTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="orderDateTv"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblorderTotalSIVATv"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Sin Iva "
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalSIVATv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="orderTotalSIVATv"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblorderTotalConIVATv"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Con Iva "
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="orderTotalTv"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LblorderCantidadTv"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Cantidad"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalProductsTv"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="orderTotalProductsTv"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderObservationsTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:maxWidth="350dp"
        android:text="orderObservationsTv"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderIdTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="orderIdTv"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"></View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser está. Ya solo queda que tu definas bien el tamaño que le darías a cada `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderIdTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="orderIdTv"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderDateTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="orderDateTv"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/LblorderTotalSIVATv"
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="Sin Iva "
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/orderTotalSIVATv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="orderTotalSIVATv"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/LblorderTotalConIVATv"
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="Con Iva "
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/orderTotalTv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:maxLines="20"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        android:text="orderTotalTv"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/LblorderCantidadTv"
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="Cantidad"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/orderTotalProductsTv"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight=".20"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="orderTotalProductsTv"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderObservationsTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:maxWidth="350dp"
            android:text="orderObservationsTv"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Así quedaría. Aunque no es buena idea del todo. Ya que en dispositivos con diferentes tamaños de pantalla no se verá igual.

[image: Preview]